# Copy Table from Excel to Word - Use Destination Styles fails

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-word-2016

I can't Paste tables from Excel into Word with the option "Use Destination Styles" anymore.

The table disappears in Word.

I have tried launching Excel and Word in safe mode but the result is the same.

[image: copy-paste]

Could you help me please ?

Alexandre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by an Office Update. I received the update during the weekend.

Office 2016 Familiy & Small Business "Click-to-Run"

Version 1805 build 9330.2118 ==> **It fails**

Version 1805 build 9330.2124 ==> **It works**